# Text breaks inside slidetoggle JS element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem on the website http://riskby.com/features/

If you scroll down a bit, and then click on the MyRiskby menu-element, the text looks like this:

[image: Text breaks after scroll in slidetoggle-element]

Here is my JS:

```
;(function ($) {
    $("#text-6").css({
        "display": "none"
    });
    $('#menu-item-990 a').click(function (event) {
        $('#text-6').slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $('#text-6').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function () {
        $('#text-6').slideUp();
    });
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var a = 1;
        var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos > a) {
            $("#text-6").css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '45px'
            });
        } else {
            $("#text-6").css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '89px'
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Can i prevent this from happening somehow?

**Status so far:** Still no solution found for this. The text-breaking happens when i scroll down a bit first, then clicking on MyRiskby... Is something wrong with my JS maybe? Every answer are very much appreciated! Thanks!

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mediabird/m186z4t7/1/

Comment: What browser? In safari it looks ok.

Comment: It happens for me in all browsers. Did you scroll down before clicking "MyRiskby"? Also try to scroll while it's toggled... Still nothing happens? :S @panther

Comment: Sorry, everything is okay at me... Maybe someone else help you if see the error :-)

Comment: Thanks for having a look at it anyways @panther! Have a great day :)

Comment: Do you have any code for menu item hover? When you hover over about or any other other item, the text is back in place

Comment: possible to make a fiddle?

Comment: Hmm yeah you're actually right @TheUknown... Text is perfect again when you hover any other menu item... Fiddle is here, but that won't say much since the error isn't showing there. But anyways: http://jsfiddle.net/mediabird/m186z4t7/1/

Comment: Also, did you notice the error occurs only if you scroll down the page a little bit. if you are at the top of the page, its fine. Might help you in debugging. Its difficult to debug this without complete menu code;css and js.

Comment: SOmething else i noticed, if you remove padding for `text6` and `widget`, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alright, i found a solution:**

Change `position` from `fixed` to `absolute`. So relatively simple ;). Works on my computer now.

Hope it can help someone else in the future.